# Managed property between SessionScoped ManagedBeans

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have the following problem!

On one of my sites i have a button:

```
<h:commandButton value="IDA Analyzer Results" action="#{SelectionBean.monitoringLog()}"/>
```

The method it calls with some part of the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "SelectionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TableSelectionBean {


private List<String> analyzerLog = new ArrayList<String>();


public String monitoringLog() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

String fileName = "/opt/IDA2/Linux/bin/"+"filtered_"+selectionMonitoringData.get(0).getMonitoringName()+"_result.txt";
if(selectionMonitoringData.get(0).getIsExecuted())
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {   
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                getAnalyzerLog().add(line);

        }   

    } finally {
        br.close();
        System.out.println(getAnalyzerLog());
    }
}
return "analyzerresult.xhtml";
}
```

After i click this button as you can see it navigates me to an other page:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>      
            <h:commandButton value="hi" action="#{AnalyzerBean.myMethod()}"></h:commandButton>       
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is the Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "AnalyzerBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AnalyzerResultBean {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{SelectionBean.analyzerLog}")
private List<String> analyzerLog;


public void myMethod(){
    System.out.print(analyzerLog);
}
    /**
     * @return the analyzerLog
     */
    public List<String> getAnalyzerLog() {
        return analyzerLog;
    }

    /**
     * @param analyzerLog the analyzerLog to set
     */
    public void setAnalyzerLog(List<String> analyzerLog) {
        this.analyzerLog = analyzerLog;
    }
```

So when I'm trying to use this Managed property it says:

The scope of the object referenced by expression #{SelectionBean.analyzerLog}, view, is shorter than the referring managed beans (AnalyzerBean) scope of session but as you can see both of the is Session Scoped. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSF 2.x and you want to navigate analyzerresult.xhtml page return analyzerresult

```
public String monitoringLog() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
  return "analyzerresult";
}
```

.xhtml extension is not needed.

Comment: Yes but it is not the problem